# No cpu metrics from running pods on stackdriver

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

Hi im trying to setup stackdriver to monitor my containers but the cpu metrics dont seem to work, im working with the following versions

```
Master Version  1.2.5
Node Version    1.2.4
heapster-v1.0.2-594732231-sil32
```

this is a group a create for the databases (it also happens for the wildfly pod and modcluster), i have a couple of other questions,

1. is it posible to monitor postgres or i have to install the agent on
   the docker image
2. can i monitor the images on kubernetes, or the disks on Google cloud?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do your containers have CPU limits specified on them? The CPU Usage graph on that page is supposed to show utilization, which is defined as `cores used / cores reserved`. If a container hasn't specified a maximum number of cores, then it won't have a utilization either, as [mentioned in the description of the CPU utilization metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#gcp-container).